# where is the apply button for unity animating?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am animating something in unity and I it keeps looping. I turned off loop time and I heard there was an apply button. I don't seem to see that. BTW my animation is set to legacy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to apply anything, just disable looping and that's it